# If $A$ is a singular matrix, then there is a matrix $B\neq 0$, so that $AB=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

True or false: If $A$ is a singular matrix, then there is a matrix $B\neq 0$, so that $AB=0$. Prove if it's true, give counterexample if it isn't.

My intuition and trials make it seem it's true, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

My gratitude in advance for any assistance!

Comment: So $A$ has a non-trivial kernel $v\neq 0$ i.e. $Av=0.$ Now can you make $B$ using $v$ only?

Comment: Sorry, we haven't studied all these yet, so I can't use this hint :(

Comment: Find a matrix $M$ such that $vM$ is square. The dimensions alone should give you a hint.

Comment: If you would like an answer based on what you've studied so far, you should perhaps explain what that is.  There are many ways to organize the ideas in a linear algebra course.

Comment: We have studied (from the syllabus): Solving linear equations, Matrices and their properties, invertible matrices. We have only now began studying the complex field (I find the course organized terribly). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Solving linear systems:

Did you learn that, if the matrix $A$ of the homogeneous system, $Ax=0$, is singular then the system has a nontrivial solution $v$? If yes, then for the matrix $B$ with all columns equal $v$, what is the product $AB$?

Comment: You mean "singular" instead of "nonsingular"

Comment: @Ted: Oops. Thanks!